# How to access sbt-plugin-project resource from sbt-plugin during a build?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have an sbt plugin project that looks like this

```
/
    src/
        main/
            resources/
                hello.txt/
    Build.scala
```

I would like to load `hello.txt` at build time in order to do stuff with it. However, when I try loading resources (or other files in general), I can only load resources from the project I'm building, and not from the plugin project. Is there any way to refer to `hello.txt` during the build? My alternative is to copy out `hello.txt` into one big multiline-string in the source code, but that feels gross.

Comment: That's surprising. Is the resource file in the plugin jar?

Comment: Yeah it's in the jar. I guess the problem is: all the keys (e.g. `resourceDirectories`) only show the relevant stuff in the being-built-project, not the plugin project, and when i print the working-directory from plugin code, it points to my being-built-project's working directory. How would I reference that file at all?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `getClass.getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("hello.txt")`.